next-auth loading wrong env info on AWS Amplify
my Nextjs application works as expected on local machine.
See whole project on GitHub
When I run it with npm run dev and access http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers I can see:
{
google: {
id: "google",
name: "Google",
type: "oauth",
signinUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/google",
callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google"
}
}

When I run it with npm run dev:test and access http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers I can see:
{
google: {
id: "google",
name: "Google",
type: "oauth",
signinUrl: "https://master.d3jm6d9zo24tlu.amplifyapp.com/api/auth/signin/google",
callbackUrl: "https://master.d3jm6d9zo24tlu.amplifyapp.com/api/auth/callback/google"
}
}

But, when I publish it to AWS Amplify (see amplify.yml) I get localhost url:
https://master.d24sg3209bakqj.amplifyapp.com/api/auth/providers
{
"google":
{
"id":"google",
"name":"Google",
"type":"oauth",
"signinUrl":"http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/google",
"callbackUrl":"http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google"
}
}


Why I'm getting localhost url?
How to fix that?
